# Laravel sql search json type column

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

The mysql has table 'subscribe' table and it's as follows:

```
column   type
id        int
condition  json
type_id    id
```

and the example as follows:

```
"id": "1",
"condition": "{\"id\":\"2\",\"class\":\"master\",\"zone\":\"west\",\"price\":\"511\"}",
"type_id": "1"
```

and I want to select the column which match in the column condition like "zone"="west"
the laravel 5.2 has support the order

```
 $subscribe = DB::table('subscribe')->where('condition->class', 'master')->get();
```

Error

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'condition->class' in 'where clause'(
SQL: select * from `subscribe` where `condition->class` = master)
```

I need is get the term which match the condition where conditon->class = master .I need to select the data which match the need in the model.
I don't know what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
 $subscribe = DB::table('subscribe')->where('condition->"$.class"', 'master')->get();
```

See the example below this paragraph, on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

> - column->path
>
> In MySQL 5.7.9 and later, the -> operator serves as an alias for the JSON_EXTRACT() function when used with two arguments, a column identifier on the left and a JSON path on the right that is evaluated against the JSON document (the column value). You can use such expressions in place of column identifiers wherever they occur in SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the where clause in query is considering as a column name in condition->class and not as a laravel code. you want to extract the value from json. but the query doesn't understand that.

What you need to do is pass entire table as it is in json format to the view and then extract in the view.

I suggest do something like this :
Here, $subscribe has entire table in json . which you can access it by :

```
$subscribe = DB::table('subscribe')->all();

return response()->json(array('subscribe' => $subscribe));
```

Then in the view do:

```
@if($subscribe->condition->class == 'master')

id      : {{ $subscribe->id }}
type id : {{ $subscribe->type_id }}

@endif
```

Updated Code

```
//get condition in json
$subscribe = DB::table('subscribe')->select('condition')->get();

then, 

// convert json to array
$subscribe_array = json_decode($subscribe, true);
//  create a new collection instance from the array
$collection_array = collect($subscribe_array);


if($collection_array['class'] == 'master')
{

//do something

}
```

Something like this do the trick

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to sent it to the view then get it, which I need is get the term which match the condition where  conditon->class = master .I need to select the data in the model .

Comment: okay. condition is the name of the column and not the json. can you try this class = 'master' instead of condition->class = 'master'

Comment: MySQL 5.7.8 added support for a native JSON data type. Laravel 5.2 now adds support for this column type.

Comment: also if you want it as condition->class. you will have to append json like this:            { "condition": { ..your data... } } and what you have is { ...your data... }

Comment: Ok, I have an idea convert json toArray() method which then can be compared using php code in controller itself. I will try to writing the code